# Find all sets of n unique rows in matrix

Tags: algorithms, optimization, matrices, search-problem

I am looking for an efficient method to find all unique combinations of $n$ rows in a matrix.

For example, if $n=6$, then I want to find all sets of 6 rows from the input set *C* in which the columns have only unique values.

Input:

```
C =
[[ 3.031  3.392  2.987  4.248  3.364  3.354]
 [ 3.031  3.392  2.987  3.975  2.911  3.354]
 [ 3.476  3.756  3.759  4.248  3.364  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.756  3.759  3.661  2.911  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.756  3.759  3.975  3.364  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.756  3.759  3.975  3.364  4.418]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  4.248  3.364  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  3.661  3.364  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  3.661  3.364  4.418]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  3.661  2.911  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  3.975  3.364  4.241]
 [ 3.476  3.899  3.759  3.975  3.364  4.418]
 [ 5.409  6.222  5.866  4.248  4.907  6.193]
 [ 5.409  6.222  5.866  3.975  4.907  6.193]
 [ 5.409  6.057  5.866  4.248  4.907  6.193]
 [ 4.725  3.899  4.196  7.183  5.255  4.241]
 [ 4.725  3.899  4.196  7.183  5.255  4.418]
 [ 7.421  6.057  7.19   8.916  5.768  5.096]
 [ 6.711  8.405  7.117  5.344  8.285  9.298]]
```

Desired Output:

```
result =
 [[ 3.031  3.392  2.987  4.248  3.364  3.354]
 [ 3.476  3.756  3.759  3.661  2.911  4.241]
 [ 5.409  6.222  5.866  3.975  4.907  6.193]
 [ 4.725  3.899  4.196  7.183  5.255  4.418]
 [ 7.421  6.057  7.19   8.916  5.768  5.096]
 [ 6.711  8.405  7.117  5.344  8.285  9.298]]
```

This is easy for a small dataset like this, however I find it hard to find a solution that scales well (when C has more than 150 rows).

**Current solution**

Iterator *It* loops over all combinations of $n$ rows. 
for $n=6$, *It* starts with indices [0,1,2,3,4,5]. These indices are used to select rows from *C*.

Until iterator *It* is done:

1. Find rows that have duplicate entries. e.g. rows 2,3 and 3,4 have duplicate entries. So duplicate indices = [2,3,4,5]
2. get lowest index of rows with. In this case: *s = 2*
3. Skip index at place *s*. In this case *s = 2* so that *It*.indices = [0,1,3,4,5,6]
4. if no duplicate entries are found, add current combination to *solutions*

In this way we don't have to check all combinations, because we skip all combinations of which we know have non-unique entries. However the computation time still rises exponentially with size of *C*.

Comment: So you want *largest* sets of rows so that each columns contains no value twice? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: if you model each row by a node in a graph and connect nodes iff the rows share at least one value, you are searching for maximum [independent sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29). That's an NP-hard problem in general. Finding *maximal* independent sets, on the other hand, can be solved in polynomial time. I don't see off the top of my head if your problem is easier.

Comment: @Raphael I do not per se want the _largest set_, rather a set of _n_ rows. However if a solution for the _largest set_ is easier, then that is also great. I will add my current solution, which works but is too slow.

Comment: No, *largest* is hard. *Maximal* solutions are such that are not a proper subset of another solution. Finding these is "easy" for Independent Set; cf Wikipedia. You should clarify in the question what exactly your input and desired output are.